# Keycloak: Get UserSessionModel of the current SSO session

Tags: keycloak, authenticator

Keycloak 11.0.2

1. Is there a way to get `UserSessionModel` assigned to current SSO session in custom Authenticator?

I am able to take a `List<UserSessionModel>`:

```
List<UserSessionModel> userSessions = context.getSession().sessions().getUserSessions(context.getRealm(), context.getUser());
```

But I don't know which filtering property may I take using `AutheticationFlowContext` to filter list against and take UserSessionModel of the current SSO session.

Now I am filtering by `UserSessionModel.id` fetched from Authentication request cookie `KEYCLOAK_SESSION` (last segment of it). Maybe there is a direct way to take `UserSessionModel.id` using `AuthenticationFlowContext` somehow?

2. I have to use `UserSessionModel.getNote()` to retrieve UserSessionNotes set previously in another Authentication flows of the same SSO.

Direct method do not works for me to take `UserSessionNotes` set in another Authentication flows (but in the same SSO):

```
@Override
public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
    Map<String,String> sessionNotes = context.getAuthenticationSession().getUserSessionNotes();
    // sessionNotes does not reflect notes set in another Authentication flows of the same SSO
    ...
```

}

So, if someone knows another way to take `UserSessionNotes` w/o `UserSessionModel` it will be also solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've received an answer at Keycloak Forum https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/getting-usersessionnotes-returns-null-while-data-persist/5172

To take `UserSessionModel` of the current SSO in Authenticator:

```
@Override
public void authenticate(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
    UserSessionModel userSessionModel;
    AuthenticationManager.AuthResult authResult = AuthenticationManager.authenticateIdentityCookie(context.getSession(),
            context.getRealm(), true);
    if (authResult != null) {
        // That is it:
        userSessionModel = authResult.getSession();
    }
```